# Python Way to Recode String Data into Categories?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

Forgive me as I am still figuring out how to clean data through Python.

I have a dataset with a column that needs cleaning. It's a string column with multiple statements, but kind of similar. I attached a frequencies table for reference: https://gyazo.com/7070364e424eae3e3e40b76cb3fba4e9

I tried to use a .str.contains with a np.where method, but the string values are too similar that it didn't work. Are there any other strategies that will help recode the column?

Here is my attempt:

```
dm = pt_df['PAT_DECISION_MAKING']

myself = dm.str.contains('Autonomous', case = True)
our_fam = dm.str.contains('family centered', case = True)
auth1 = dm.str.contains('authority figure', case = True)
both = dm.str.contains('a.|b.', case = True)

pt_df['PAT_DECISION_MAKING'] = np.where(myself, 'Myself',
                                   np.where(our_fam, 'Family Centered',
                                            np.where(auth1, 'Authority Figure',
                                                     np.where(both, 'Multiple',
                                                              es.str.replace('-', '')))))

pt_df['PAT_DECISION_MAKING'] = pd.Categorical(pt_df.PAT_DECISION_MAKING)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help to cast the column as category, then recast as a category. After doing so you can then easily convert to categories using cat.codes.

1. Make your column a category dtype

`pt_df['PAT_DECISION_MAKING'] = pt_df['PAT_DECISION_MAKING'].astype('category')`

2. Take this column and assign categorical codes.

`pt_df['PAT_DECISION_MAKING'] = pt_df['PAT_DECISION_MAKING'].apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)`

[Read more on categorical codes](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.Categorical.codes.html).